# Recyclerview se mueve cuando agrego texto a un item

Tags: android, recyclerview

Hago el parseo de la información para agregar a una lista y a su vez, agregarlo al `recyclerview`. Dentro de cada **item** hay un botón que realiza una función y dentro de esa función es cambiar un texto pero cuando se da click en este botón el `recyclerview` se desplaza hacia abajo y se pierde el item al que se dio click.

**Mi clase:**

```
DataLife dataLife = new DataLife();
dataLife.totalMeGusta = totalMeGusta;
dataLife.imagen = imagen;
data.add(dataLife);

LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);

rv.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
rv.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
lifeAdapter = new LifeAdapter(getActivity(), data);
rv.setAdapter(lifeAdapter);
```

**Viewholder:**

```
myHolder.ivLike.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                 myHolder.txtLike.setText("A "+String.valueOf(totalMeGusta)+" personas les gusta");

}
        });
```

**Item:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="@dimen/margin_item_list"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView"
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"/>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtCategoria"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                        android:textColor="@color/VWGreyDark"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        android:text="Nombre Categoría"/>

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="4"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/margin_item_list"
                android:text="Noticia"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:textColor="@color/VWBlueDark"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />

            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/webView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="-8dp">
            </WebView>

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"/>

            <com.ms.square.android.expandabletextview.ExpandableTextView
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:expandableTextView="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/expand_text_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                expandableTextView:maxCollapsedLines="2"
                expandableTextView:animDuration="200">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@id/expandable_text"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:textSize="13dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="3dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/VWGreyDark" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@id/expand_collapse"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="16dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

            </com.ms.square.android.expandabletextview.ExpandableTextView>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0.5dp"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:background="@color/VWGreyLight"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#EFEFF4"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/relativeLike"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="4">

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/ivLike"
                        android:layout_width="25dp"
                        android:layout_height="25dp"
                        android:background="#EFEFF4"
                        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                        android:src="@mipmap/like_normal"/>

                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_weight="1">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtLike"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="@color/VWBlueDark"
                        android:textSize="11dp"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        android:text="Número de likes"/>

                </RelativeLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Puedes mostrar el xml del adapter?

Comment: Te refieres al xml de cada item en el recycler?

Comment: Si, a eso me referia.

Comment: Listo, ya edité la pregunta.

Comment: Al parecer el problema está cuando hago un cambio en algún item, por ejemplo, cuando pongo en GONE el progressbar o cuando edito el contenido del textview.

Comment: ¿Le ha sucedido algo parecido o sabe la manera en que pueda corregir eso?

Comment: Ok para ayudarte tienes que dar mas detalles. Puedes especificar cual es el TextView que estas modificando y el codigo que lo modifica? Si hay algun otro elemento que es modificado que provoca el comportamiento indeseado, favor especificarlo tambien. Intenta tambien agregar un print screen de como esta antes y despues de la modificacion.